# Eclipse Memory Analyzer: How to import analyze result from remote MAT by ParseHeapDump.sh?

Tags: java, memory, heap-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I have a large heap dump file in the remote server. And I run MAT's ParseHeapDump.sh file remotely. How can I import those analyzed files (dump.*.index) to my local MAT? I don't want to download the huge heap dump file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like dump.*.index is just index file and I will whatever need to download the entire heap dump file

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the analysis results, you need to copy just the zip file containing those results. For example, if you used the MAT to generate "Leak suspects" report, the results would be stored as HTMLs in a zip file whose name ends with *"_Leak_Suspects.zip"*. This file is much smaller than the heap dump. You could copy this file to you local machine and analyze the report. Here is an article that explain this - https://javaforu.blogspot.com/2013/11/analyzing-large-java-heap-dumps-when.html